# FlutterのStreamBuilderでローディングしているかどうかを補足したい

Tags: stream, flutter

現在Flutterの勉強としてStreamBuilderを使用して簡単なRSSリーダーを作成しています。
StreamBuilderを使用してRSSフィードを取得（http.getによって取得）してリスト表示するところまではできました。
また、画面をオーバースクロールすることで新しいフィードを取得してリストに追加することもできました。
しかし、オーバースクロールして新しいフィードを取得している時にローディング画面を出すことができずにいます。具体的には、オーバースクロールすることで新しいフィードの取得は開始されますが、このフィードの取得状態(取得処理中なのか、取得処理完了なのか)をどのようにして補足できるのかがわかりません。
当初はconnectionStateがwaitingであるかどうかで補足できると考えておりましたが、
connectionStateは常にactive状態になっており、思う動作を実現できませんでした。
Flutter、Streamについて理解が不足している部分が多々あるため、質問自体が不明瞭かもしれませんが、何かしらヒントや解決策、読むべきドキュメント等あればご教示頂きたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:./entry_model.dart';

class EntryList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _EntryListState createState() => _EntryListState();
}

class _EntryListState extends State<EntryList>
    with
        AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<EntryList> {
  EntriesModel entriesModel;
  StreamController _itemsController;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final formatter = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd(E) HH:mm', 'ja_JP');

  Future fetchEntries() async {
    final response = await entriesModel.getEntries();
    return response;
  }

  Future fetchNewEntries() async {
    final response = await entriesModel.getNewEntries();
    return response;
  }

  loadEntries() async {
    fetchEntries().then((res) async {
      _itemsController.add(res);
      return res;
    });
  }

  loadNewEntries() async {
    fetchNewEntries().then((res) async {
      _itemsController.add(res);
      return res;
    });
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    entriesModel = EntriesModel();
    _itemsController = StreamController();
    loadEntries();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _itemsController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var numberOfItem = 0;

    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldkey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: // オーバースクロールで新しいフィードを取得中にここでローディング中であるメッセージを表示したい。,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 20,
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: _itemsController.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {

                  numberOfItem = snapshot.data.length as int;

                  return numberOfItem == 0
                      ? Center(child: const Text('Empty'))
                      : RefreshIndicator(
                      onRefresh: () => _onRefresh(),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data == null
                              ? 0
                              : numberOfItem,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final item = snapshot.data[index] as Entry;
                            return _buildCard(item, index, context)
                          })
                       );
                } else {
                  return const Text('No data');
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onRefresh() async {
    await loadNewEntries();
  }
}

Card _buildCard(Entry item, int index, BuildContext context) {
  return Card( // 各フィードをCard形式で表示 
  );
}
```

上記のコード内のEntriesModelがフィードを扱うモデルで、getEntries()でSQLiteに保存しているフィードを読み込んで、getNewEntries()でhttp.getを使って新しいフィードを読み込んでいます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_itemsController`にはデータしか流れないため、状態までは分からないですね。
そのため状態も分かるようにするため、状態用のクラスを用意し、データはこのクラスに内包させる方法はどうでしょうか。

**状態用のクラス**

```dart
abstract class FetchState {}

class Fetching extends FetchState {}

class Fetched extends FetchState {
  Fetched({this.entryList});
  /// 取得したデータ
  List<Entry> entryList;
}
```

**データ取得の実装**

```dart
loadEntries() async {
  _itemsController.add(Fetching());
  fetchEntries().then((res) async {
    _itemsController.add(Fetched(entryList: res));
    return res;
  });
}
```

**StreamBuilderの実装**

```dart
child: StreamBuilder(
  stream: _itemsController.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data is Fetching) {
        // データ取得中
        ～処理～
      } else if (snapshot.data is Fetched) {
        // データ取得完了
        // snapshot.data.entryList からデータを取得
        ～処理～
      }
    }
  },
),
```